# Javascript: Sort li items alphabetically by data attribute without jquery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort a list alphabetically only using javascript.

I've already none a similar function using jquery like this:

```
$('.articles').append($('#articles-non-attached li'));
        var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.articles li').sort(function(a, b) {
            return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('title').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('title').toLowerCase());
        });
```

But now I need to use just Javascript.

So far I've got:

```js
var stores_li = document.querySelectorAll('.store-list-item');

//stores_li.sort();

[].slice.call(stores_li).sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase()
    var textB = b.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase()
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
    //return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(textA,textB);

});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="a">Test 1</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="c">Test 3</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="b">Test 2</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="d">Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: It's not sorting alphabetically. It should return Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Test 4.
But it's returning test 1, test 3, test 2, test 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to append the newly sorted items.

```js
var stores_li = document.querySelectorAll('.store-list-item');

[].slice.call(stores_li).sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase()
    var textB = b.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase()
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
})
  .forEach(function(el) {el.parentNode.appendChild(el)});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="a">Test 1</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="c">Test 3</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="b">Test 2</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="d">Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

This is because the native `.sort()` method isn't a DOM method; it just sorts any arbitrary list of Array items. So by appending the newly sorted item, it commits the new element order to the DOM.

Note that the simple solution above assumes they all share the same parent.

---

Here's a version with modern syntax and methods:

```js
var stores_li = document.querySelectorAll('.store-list-item');

Array.from(stores_li).sort((a, b) =>   
  a.dataset.title.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.dataset.title.toLowerCase())
)
  .forEach(el => el.parentNode.appendChild(el));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="a">Test 1</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="c">Test 3</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="b">Test 2</li>
  <li class="store-list-item" data-title="d">Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was gonna post the exact same solution as your second, more modern one. Only I believe there's no need for `.toLowerCase()` since everything is already lowercase. Good job.

Comment: @JohnnyKutnowski: Thanks, and you're right, unless the OP isn't sure about the case, the `.toLowerCase()` is superfluous.

Comment: Thank you so much @llama! Worked perfectly :)

Comment: @llama Nice! It worked great.The events still work after the elements are put back as well. I however suggest that you put the modern syntax on top. I picked the old syntax because it was the first thing I saw.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stores_li = document.querySelectorAll('.store-list-item');
var sorted = [].slice.call(stores_li).sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.dataset.title.toLowerCase();
    var textB = b.dataset.title.toLowerCase();

    return textA.localeCompare(textB);
});
```

Comment: This is a fine answer but needs some explanation